# Как делать оценку узла дерева минимакса в шашках?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Разбираюсь с алгоритмом минимакса на основе игры шашки. 
Далее изложение моего понимания работы алгоритма со этой задачей:

Для каждого узла дерева мы можем получить оценку: 0 - ничего не произошло, 1 - была съедена шашка противника.

```
  0
 / \
0   A
   / \
  0   B
```

Тут если в А и B была съедена шашка, то какой результат должен оказаться в A? Т.е. мы же не можем дать оценку только на основании терминальной позиции B, т.к. в A тоже произошло событие поедания шашки соперника.

Т.е. если у нас от этого узла отходят дочерние и в них тоже есть оценка (т.е. в них тоже была съедена шашка), то какую результирующую выбирать?

Спасибо!

Comment: По правилам шашек «есть» – обязательно, если есть возможность. Но Вы можете *представить*, что будет, если остановиться в А.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучив статьи и посоветовавшись пришел к такому заключению:

Необходима оценочная функция, которая дает оценку общему состоянию дел на доске.
Т.е. необходимо учитывать и давать оценку на основе:

- Разницы между количеством съеденных своих и чужих шашек
- Разницы между количеством своих дамок и противника
- Расстоянии шашек от первой линии противника (только тех, что еще не дамки)
- Разницы в количестве возможных своих ходов и противника (заблокированные шашки)

Использовать оценочную функцию следует в терминальных узлах дерева, таким образом получая оценку именно данной ветки. Далее все по пунктам указанным в алгоритме минимакса.

Answer (score 0):

не понял для чего это, но я предлогаю следующее:

1. Для позиции В хранить число 1. так как одно съедание.
2. для позиции А хранить 2. где 1 до А и еще 1 до В (1+1=2)

но я бы сделал еще по веткам.

Для текущей точки: (к примеру А)

1. была ли съедена шашка до этой точки.
2. сколько съедено если пойти по левой ветки
3. сколько съедено если пойти по правой ветки
4. общее количество съедание